# Ensure runtime licenses are activated with no executable

Tags: .net, deployment, licensing

We're using a third party licensed product, which requires a call to an "ActivateRuntimeLicense" method in the executable such that when deployed, our clients aren't asked for the license.  This works fine.

However, another part of the deployment means we call into our code from elsewhere (actually, a GIS system), so there's only the library (dll).  We have a large number of static methods that the GIS calls.

How can I ensure licensing works correctly in this scenario?

Thanks,
Melanie

Comment: only way to really ensure it would be to execute that EXE from the dll...  you could stick something in the registry to keep track of whether it was called or not so you only do it once.  Is there any registration process for this dll?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: yes, that turns out to be the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to really ensure it would be to execute that EXE from the dll... you could stick something in the registry to keep track of whether it was called or not so you only do it once. Is there any registration process for this dll